# Automatically open terminal when debugging in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, automation, terminal

When debugging an executable in Xcode, I very often have to open up a terminal window, navigate to the executable's working directory and do some work there. Is there any way to have Xcode automatically open a terminal window at this location each time I debug my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Xcode, go to your **Target**, then right-click and choose:

`Add -> New Build Phase -> New Run Script Build Phase`

[image]

then add the following:

```
open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app
```

[image]

Now, every time you Build your app, Xcode will run this build script and launch Terminal. Note that you need to point to the correct location of the terminal application. Best way to do this is find the Terminal.app and drag and drop it onto the above screen after you type "open".

Once you have Terminal open, you will need to make an AppleScript to send the commands to Terminal to open the specific directory. Use the 'osascript' command to
send an AppleEvent to Terminal.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who's still looking,

It's really easy.. say you want to click run and have the app run in the Terminal. Here's what you do:

Go to Build Phases -> Editor -> Add Build Phase -> Add Run Script Build Phase -> Click the down arrow on Run Script -> Add the following:

open /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app /Users/yourusername/restofpath

Notes: Spaces use '\ ' if needed. Include your app name in the path. Don't use quotes.

Click Run, and there you go!

If you want the Terminal to clear, in your source code type 'system("clear")' near main(). It's the only solution I have while debugging. Works great.

Comment: make sure to paste the path part next to the "1", not in the shell text box. This confused me for a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31971610/1499350) to see how to setup Xcode scheme to fully automate debugging with using Terminal. I described it for ncurses that requires real Terminal to work.