# Xcode and Curses.h with Error opening terminal

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc, terminal, curses

I am trying to compile a simple curse project with Xcode.
 
The program compiles fine with g++ in terminal with the flag -lcurses, and runs fine.

Started of by creating a Command Line Tool with type c++.
imported curses.h into my main.
In the Target"program"Info -> General -> Linked Libraries, libCurses.dylib has been added.

It compiles fine but the terminal window will not open.
 
In the Debug Console the output is,

Program loaded.
run
[Switching to process 3424]
Error opening terminal: unknown.
Running…

I can go to build folder and just open the program in terminal but is there any way for xcode to open the terminal?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem with ncurses debugging in Xcode. Finally I've found a good way for me to manage debugging with Terminal.app that allows to debug ncurses.

As we know, to initialise and use ncurses we need to run our application in terminal. But Xcode doesn't open terminal when we press run button. So, if we request environment variable `TERM` from code, we'll get `NULL`. This is why application crashes on `initscr()`.

So, it is needed to launch Terminal.app, execute our process there and attach a debugger to it. It can be achieved through Scheme setup. I did it in Xcode 11.4. I created a new macOS Command Line Tool project based on `Language:` `C++`. Also I added `libncurses.tbd` dependency in `Frameworks and Libraries`.

Go to `Product > Scheme > Edit scheme...`, select `Run` scheme and `Run` action and navigate to `Info` tab. You'll see `Launch` set to `Automatically`. Change it to `Wait for the executable to be launched`.
[image]

Select `Pre-actions` in the `Run` scheme and add `New Run Script Action`. Change `Provide build settings from` from `None` to your build target. Add the following code there:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"' -e 'delay 0.5' -e 'activate' -e "do script (\"$TARGET_BUILD_DIR/$PRODUCT_NAME\")" -e 'end tell' &
```

[image]

To optionally close terminal in the end of debugging session select `Post-actions` in the `Run` scheme and add `New Run Script Action`. Add the following code:

```
osascript -e 'activate application "Terminal"' -e 'delay 0.5' -e 'tell application "System Events"' -e 'tell process "Terminal"' -e 'keystroke "w" using {command down}' -e 'end tell' -e 'end tell'
```

[image]
Actually osascript will always create at least two terminal windows but if you will leave the first one opened it will create and destroy the second one with your session automatically through Pre and Post actions.

You will probably also meet a problem with debugger attaching. I don't know exact reason why Xcode don't want to attach debugger when process executes externally but I found this issue. Also I found `stdin` stream in weird state during debugging session beginning as well. So, I wrote a workaround based on `pselect` call. I'm asking `stdin` for any data until it doesn't return success. I found that after these manipulations debugger will feel OK and `stdin` requests will be OK as well. Here is my code example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

bool g_has_terminal = false; // Check this global variable before ncurses calls

bool ensure_debugger_attached_woraround(int timeout_ms)
{
    fd_set fd_stdin;
    FD_ZERO(&fd_stdin);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fd_stdin);
    struct timespec timeout = { timeout_ms / 1000, (timeout_ms % 1000) * 1000000 };

    do
    {
        errno = 0;
    }
    while (pselect(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fd_stdin, NULL, NULL, &timeout, NULL) < 0 && errno == EINTR);

    if (errno != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected error %d", errno);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (!ensure_debugger_attached_woraround(700))
        return 1;

    char *term = getenv("TERM");

    g_has_terminal = (term != NULL);

    if (g_has_terminal)
        g_has_terminal = (initscr() != NULL);

    // Some ncurses code. Maybe you should terminate if g_has_terminal is not set

    if (g_has_terminal)
    {
        printw("Press any key to exit...");
        refresh();

        getch();

        endwin();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`ensure_debugger_attached_woraround` is called with a timeout 700 milliseconds. I tried different values and found 500 ms is the minimal one to not skip `pselect`. Maybe this timeout is machine depended I don't know. You can wrap this call by `#ifdef ... #endif` or by some other checks, maybe by special command line argument check to exclude a little wait overhead in the release mode.

Comment: well played @C0DEF52.  This is a lot of hops but they still work, 4years after your post.  Without these steps, using `Xcode` and `ncurses` would be zero fun.

Comment: @rustyMagnet I'm happy that you found the solution useful.

Answer (score 6):

In XCode 8 you can choose to run within the terminal, from the Edit Scheme... Options page.
[image: XCode 8 screenshot]

Though in my quick testing it doesn't seem to work all that well; it sometimes (not always) seems to 'lose' the debuggee, or the debuggee never starts, and thinks it's still running. If you try to exit, Xcode gets stuck. I have found that if you find and then kill a process called `lldb-rpc-server` you can avoid having to force-quit.

In more detail (in case this helps anyone) whenever the debuggee fails to start, I open a Terminal and type

```
ps x | grep lldb
```

then

```
kill 12345
```

where `12345` is the process ID that ps gives me.

Comment: Nice find. Had the same problem -- doesn't actually work, but neat to know that they're working on it. Also had to kill the process as you mentioned after it failed to do much of anything.

Comment: Glad it's not just me. I'd guess about 20% of the time I have to kill the process. Even when it does 'work', the debugger quite often triggers on signals (SIGSTOP mostly) which I wouldn't have expected. Here's waiting for XCode 9 (!)

Answer (score 4):

There is no terminal to attach to in the Xcode IDE.
Instead run the program from a shell (via Terminal application)

```
./build/Debug/myprogram
```

If you want to use the IDE debugger (which is just gdb) you can attach
to the process. Fist get the process id,

```
gdb> attach mypid
```

For a more convenient method, I'll quote Step into Xcode: Mac OS X development

> Open the Executables group in the
>   *Groups & Files* list, select the application, open an Info window, and
>   in the Debugging tab, uncheck *Start
>   executable after starting debugger*.
>   When you're ready to debug, start the
>   debugger, and then then launch the
>   target application in its friendly
>   environment. In the debugger's gdb
>   console, type *attach myprogram*, and
>   your debugging sesssion is under way.

Answer (score 0):

Follow on to Peter Hull's answer, selecting "Console - Use Terminal" in the Scheme->Run->Options worked for me too.

Regarding the lldb-rpc-server which does not exit properly:  One can simply add the following to the Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Run->Post-actions:

`ps -ef |grep lldb-rpc-server |grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | sort -rn | while read PID ; do kill $PID ; done`

This will find the lldb-rpc-server processes, which should be owned by your userid anyway, sort them in reverse order, and simply dispatch them.

[image: Xcode-Run-PostAction-kill-lldb-rpc-server]

This helped me a lot!  I hope it helps someone else too!

-TechnoPak