# Can you not use <ncurses.h> on Mac C++ systems? Attempting to make a simple snake game

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, ncurses

I am attempting to create a snake game for a class using C++ on Xcode, but this code is not working for me. The errors I am receiving state that all of my curses symbols are undefined.
The 13 errors found in my code are:

- Undefined symbol: _cbreak
- Undefined symbol: _clear
- Undefined symbol: _curs_set
- Undefined symbol: _endwin
- Undefined symbol: _halfdelay
- Undefined symbol: _initscr
- Undefined symbol: _keypad
- Undefined symbol: _mvprintw
- Undefined symbol: _noecho
- Undefined symbol: _refresh
- Undefined symbol: _stdscr
- Undefined symbol: _wgetch

Please let me know! I've spent hours trying to look this up and am not sure what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ncurses.h>

bool gameOver;
const int width = 20, height = 20;
int x,y, FruitX, FruitY, score;
enum eDirection {STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};
eDirection dir;

int TailX[100], TailY[100];
int nTail = 0;

void Setup() {
    
    initscr();
    clear();
    noecho();
    cbreak();
    curs_set(0);
    
    gameOver = false;
    dir = STOP;
    x = width/2;
    y = height/2;
    FruitX = (rand() % width) + 1;
    FruitY = (rand() % height) + 1;
    score = 0;
    
}

void Draw() {
    
    clear();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < width + 2; i++)
        mvprintw(0, i, "+");
    
    for (int i = 0; i < height + 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width + 2; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0 | i ==21)
                mvprintw(i, j, "#");
            else if (j == 0 | j == 21)
                mvprintw(i, j, "+");
            else if (i == y && j == x)
                mvprintw(i, j, "0");
            else if (i == FruitY && j == FruitX)
                mvprintw(i, j, "0");
            else
                for (int k = 0; k < nTail; k++)
                {
                    if (TailX[k] == j && TailY[k] == i)
                        mvprintw(i, j, "o");
                }
        }
    }
    
    mvprintw(23, 0, "Score %d", score);
    
    refresh();
    
    
}

void Input() {
    
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
    halfdelay(1);
    
    int c = getch();
    
    switch(c)
    {
    case KEY_LEFT:
        dir = LEFT;
        break;
    case KEY_RIGHT:
        dir = RIGHT;
        break;
    case KEY_UP:
        dir = UP;
        break;
    case KEY_DOWN:
        dir = DOWN;
        break;
    case 113:
            gameOver = true;
            break;
    }
    
}

void Logic() {
    
    int prevX = TailX[0];
    int prevY = TailY[0];
    int prev2X, prev2Y;
    
    TailX[0] = x;
    TailY[0] = y;
    
    for (int i = 1; i < nTail; i++)
    {
        prev2X = TailX[i];
        prev2Y = TailY[i];
        TailX[i] = prevX;
        TailY[i] = prevY;
        prevX = prev2X;
        prevY = prev2Y;
    }
    
    switch (dir) {
        case LEFT:
            x--;
            break;
        case RIGHT:
            x++;
            break;
        case UP:
            y--;
            break;
        case DOWN:
            y++;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    
    if (x > width || x < 1 || y > height){
        gameOver = true;
    }
    if (x == FruitX && y == FruitY)
    {
        score++;
        FruitX = (rand() % width)+1;
        FruitY = (rand() % height)+1;
        nTail++;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nTail; i++)
        if (TailX[i] == x && TailY[i] == y)
        {
            gameOver = true;
        }
}

int main() {

    Setup();
    
    while(!gameOver)
    {
        Draw();
        Input();
        Logic();
    }
    
    getch();
    endwin();
    
    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: I linked `libcurses.tbd` and `libncurses.tbd` and the error warnings went away and the build did not fail. However, instead of running how it is supposed to, it now only produces the lines,

"Error opening terminal: unknown.
Program ended with exit code: 1"

help.

Comment: Show how you linked to the library

Comment: sooooo apparently I did not link it to the library and that is what my issue was. Definitely a beginner here. I just linked libcurses.tbd and libncurses.tbd. The errors are now gone but now it is only executing 
"Error opening terminal: unknown.
Program ended with exit code: 1"

Comment: @JaMiT My bad. I meant the build succeeded, in contrast to the past where the build failed each time due to the errors. However, it is still definitely not "succeeding" as it's not running at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xcode and Curses.h with Error opening terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919373/xcode-and-curses-h-with-error-opening-terminal)