# How to build an Xcode c++ program on terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, ncurses

I am using Xcode to program c++ projects. I am using ncurses library.
I am create a simple example, which works fine on terminal, but it does not work using xcode.

```
#include<ncurses.h>
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    char c;
    initscr();
    printw("Hello world!");
    refresh();
    c=getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;

}
```

On Xcode I get this error 
***Error opening terminal: unknown.***

I am wondering that Xcode is not able to emulate an terminal. So, I try to change the "build phase" in xcode in order to build my project on terminal. I have used the proposed solution [Automatically open terminal when debugging in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553623/automatically-open-terminal-when-debugging-in-xcode)
But my project continue to run on xcode. What is the problem?

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31971610/1499350 with the same problem